# Can you Awaken something that is alive?

Tags: cosmere, warbreaker

Is it possible to Awaken something that is already alive, thereby gaining control over the being?

Comment: Good question. I suspect that, if you can, it might be limited to something without Breath.

Comment: No. Breath in a person has the person's [identity](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Identity), not someone else's and even otherwise living things *aren't* usually powered by breath. Only other case is Nightblood - that's kinda only life controlled by command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes and no. Technically it seems you can "awaken" living things, as there is a scene in Warbreaker in which Vasher tells a girl a command phrase for making herself forget. However, since he makes the girl repeat the words, rather than commanding her himself, it seems that you can only do this on yourself.